# How to use Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit

Tags: dynamics-crm, development-environment, toolkit, dynamics-365

I installed Latest Version of Developer Toolkit for vs2015 and after that when i use toolkit to connect to CRM, after click on connect button it does not do anything. no error, no success action,
i delete every Cache data and every Temp data and Clear my solution but nothing change,
do you have any idea? help me please because i want to develop custom workflow step and develop plugins with this toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft's Developer's Toolkit has been dormant for quite some time.

Current options are:

[Jason Lattimer's Developer Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JLattimer.D365DeveloperExtensions)
Which is also [on GitHub](https://github.com/jlattimer/D365DeveloperExtensions).

Or the commercial add-on [XrmToolkit](https://www.xrmtoolkit.com), which has a 30-day free trial.

If you go with Jason's solution and you're looking to do early bound development you might want to also look into [XrmToolbox's](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com) [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator) by Daryl LaBar.

The XrmToolkit includes its own proprietary proxy class generator.